# C# UWP XML Serialization TreeView

Tags: c#, serialization, uwp, treeview

i have a simple Treeview for UWP (It is a external Control from Microsoft because UWP does not include a Treeview). I want to save Serialized the Tree to XML. I tried following Code

```
 public static async void SaveTree(TreeView tree, string filename)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\IT\source\repos\App3\App3");
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("test.xml");
        using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
               Stream s = writeStream.AsStream();
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(s, tree.RootNode.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());
        }
    }
```

But it gives always a unknown error. Maybe is this a wrong function for UWP?
Anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: You should be serializing the data, not the actual treenode control itself. Is the tree populated from a view model/model?

Comment: The tree is populated from a Folder structur. But i want to delete this structur and work only with XML Files.

Comment: That is fine, but what you should be doing is when you read the folder structure, create a model and then use that model to populate the treeview and use that model again to serialize to XML. You can't serialize a treenode.

Comment: the Goal is to delete the Folder structur and load the tree from the XML file. So it is possible to serialize this tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry there is no way to do it in UWP.